# apply transform to image uploaded into Redactor?

Tags: redactor, image-transforms

Is it possible to allow the selection of an image transform on an image that's been uploaded into a Redactor field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, from the Redactor "Insert Image" modal:

[image]

Comment: got it, never saw it on this Redactor field because the image wasn't enabled within the config. In the case of this post, the article was copied and pasted from another source, so I assume because the image wasn't a true Asset but rather just a reference, that's why it doesn't show the transforms?

Comment: "the image wasn't enabled within the config" - not sure I'm following.

Comment: the option to upload an Asset wasn't enabled. The image had been pasted from another source and as far as I can make out, you can't apply a transform to that kind of image within Redactor?

Answer (score 2):

When it pops up with the Craft UI modal to select an image asset you can select a transform in the bottom right

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the free [Retcon plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/retcon) to apply named or inline transforms at the template level, using Craft's native transforms or [Imager](https://plugins.craftcms.com/imager) if you have that installed as well. This isn't limited to Redactor fields, but any HTML at all.

Examples from the documentation:

```
{{ entry.body | retconTransform( 'yourNamedTransform' ) }}
```

```
{{ entry.body | retconTransform( { width : 1024, height : 768, mode : 'fit' } ) }}
```