# Force an image transform to images inserted into Redactor

Tags: image-transforms

I know [this essentially does the trick](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8271/apply-transform-to-image-uploaded-into-redactor), however I was hoping I could apply a custom transform to all image assets if one **hasn't** been defined by the user.

The problem I have is trying to convey the importance of defining image transforms to my "less-than-savvi" clients.

So, as a fallback I'd like to know if I can query any images and apply an image transform. I feel like this might be a step in the right direction, but not sure what to do next:

```
{{ include(template_from_string(entry.body)|raw) }}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a plugin called [Retcon](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) which is able to apply [bulk image transforms](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Transform) to images in HTML/Redactor content:

```
{{ entry.body|retconTransform({ width : 1024 }) }}
{{ entry.body|retconTransform(myAwesomeTransform) }}
```

There's currently no way to tell Retcon to only transform images that hasn't already been transformed, though – so this might not be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Very nice, thanks Mats. Apologies for the late reply too!