# How to force a default transform on existing content within a Redactor field

Tags: redactor, image-transforms

There isn't much documentation out there about how to apply [image transforms](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/image-transforms.html) to images in a Redactor field.

**I found this**: [Apply transform to image uploaded into Redactor?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8271/apply-transform-to-image-uploaded-into-redactor)

And it's useful, since I can even select a default transform:

[image]

... but I would like to go a bit further, and not only apply transforms to new content, but also to all the entries witin a specific section that uses a Redactor field.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the Retcon plugin to do this. https://plugins.craftcms.com/retcon

Comment: Hi James, thanks. I've looked into the plugin but with this one I'd have to explicit it in my twig templates. I want the transforms to be done on the server before it even processes the twig template.

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is: use the [Image Optimize](https://nystudio107.com/docs/image-optimize/) plugin.

```
php craft image-optimize/optimize/create
```

More console commands in the [official docs](https://nystudio107.com/docs/image-optimize/using.html#console-commands).